# Validating data using FirestoreDataConverter

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to do some kind of data validation when using `FirestoreDataConverter<T>`?

Looking at the call signature for `fromFirestore`, it seems like you can only return `T`. But what if I look at the data and realize that there is invalid data in the database? (I know, I should guard against that in the first place, but bad things happen.)

And it is even more important to guard against errors when using `toFirestore`. Again, is there a recommended way to do data validation before writing to the database?

I ask because looking at the [VueFire documentation](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/guide/realtime-data.html#firestore-withconverter) , they seem to return null on invalid data. Is that simply an error on their part?

I can see two options. Include some kind of error-state type in the signature (`FirestoreDataConverter<T|E>`) or throw an error. Is one or the other the 'recommended practice'?

I wish the official docs had more information on how to use `FirestoreDataConverter`.

Comment: You can use `Firestore rules` to validate data as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72008730/18265570) and also check this [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/c5DwcQJb4F4/m/uen3xnP7AgAJ)

Comment: Rules is a good final defense against bad data going in, but no validation of data going out of the DB

Comment: You have to implement server side logic based on your business requirement. You may check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61626199/18265570) once.